# How does Connection.prototype.useDb() method in mongoose works under the hood?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-connection, connection-pooling, multi-database-connections

I am trying to understand the [Connection.prototype.useDb()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.useDb()) method better. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

1.
The mongoose document for [useDb()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.useDb()) states:

> Switches to a different database using the same connection pool.

Does this mean that if there is an available connection in the connection pool `useDb('db1')` will reuse the connection? in other words can a connection used by `useDb('db1')`, be reused by `useDb('db2')`?
Or does the statement simply mean that `useDb('db1')` will create a new connection in the connection pool and can only reuse connections already created by `useDb('db1')`?

2.
The mongoose document for [useDb()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.useDb()) states:

> [options.useCache=false] «Boolean» If true, cache results so calling useDb() multiple times with the same name only creates 1 connection object.

What happens in the following scenario(assuming that [`maxIdleTimeMS`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/faq/#how-can-i-prevent-a-slow-operation-from-delaying-other-operations-:%7E:text=Once%20a%20connection%20has%20been%20idle%20for%20maxIdleTimeMS%2C%20the%20connection%20pool%20removes%20and%20replaces%20it.%20This%20option%20defaults%20to%200%20(no%20limit).) equals 0 which means no limit and [maxPoolSize](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/#:%7E:text=means%20no%20minimum.-,maxPoolSize,-non%2Dnegative%20integer) equals 2)?
[image]
3.
Considering:

> [options.useCache=false] «Boolean» If true, cache results so calling useDb() multiple times with the same name only creates 1 connection object.

and considering [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/faq/#how-can-i-prevent-a-slow-operation-from-delaying-other-operations-) from mongodb.com which states:

> MongoDB is synchronous and uses a single execution thread per socket, meaning that MongoDB will execute one single operation per socket at any point in time. Any other operation sent to that socket will have to wait until the current operation is finished.

Does this mean 5 queries which are supposed to be executed on `mydb2`, using the connection from `conn.useDb('mydb2', { useCache: true })`, would have to wait in queue to be executed one after another? as opposed to  `conn.useDb('mydb2', { useCache: false })`, which means they will be executed on separate connections and in parallel?

**EDIT**
Since mongoose uses Nodejs mongo driver's [db method](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7971a4dbd55888f0b005e65b06024109af8352f7/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js#L103) to implement its `useDb` method, and since the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#id1) for `db()` method in mongo driver states:

> Create a new Db instance sharing the current socket connections.

I guess this means that each connection(socket) in the connection pool can be shared regardless whether they were created by calling `conn.useDb('mydb1')` or `conn.useDb('mydb2')`

Answer (score 0):

I conducted certain experiments to be able to understand how `useDb` works by examining it's behavior in certain situations.

## useDb() reuses connections in the connection pool

### Experiment

1. create a connection with `maxPoolSize = 1`(only 1 connection(socket) allowed in the connection pool) and `socketTimeoutMS = 30000`(MongoDB driver kills a connection(socket) after 30 seconds of inactivity)
2. call `conn.useDb('db1')` which creates a new connection or uses an existing connection from the connection pool
3. right after step 2(under 30 seconds after step two), call `conn.useDb('db2')` and execute a query on the returned connection, the query runs without being blocked and waiting for 30 seconds for the connection to get killed.
   which shows that since only 1 connection(socket) is allowed in the connection pool and each connection will at least stay on the pool for 30 seconds(in case there are no errors) then it seems that the socket is being reused(*although it might also mean that the mongo driver kills the connection created by `conn.useDb('db1')` and creates a new socket for `conn.useDb('db2')`*).

### Result

It seems like if there is an available connection(socket) in the connection pool `conn.useDb` will reuse the connection, in other words a connection used/created by `conn.useDb('db1')`, can be reused by `conn.useDb('db2')`.

## { useCache: true } does not block

### Experiement

1. create a connection with `maxPoolSize = 2` and `socketTimeoutMS = 30000`
2. execute a slow operation(long running query which runs for 20 seconds) on the connection returned by `conn.useDb('db1', { useCache: true })`("MongoDB uses a single execution thread per socket" which means this connection won't be available for 20 seconds, which means only one connection will be available in the connection pool)
3. right after step 2(in less than 20 seconds), we execute a fast query on the connection returned by `conn.useDb('db1', { useCache: true })` and it gets executed instantly

This shows that instead of waiting for the cached connection to get returned, the second `conn.useDb('db1', { useCache: true })` call will either create a new connection or use another available connection from the pool and does not wait for the cached connection.

### Result

It **does not** mean that 5 queries which are supposed to be executed on `db2`, using the connection from `conn.useDb('db2', { useCache: true })`, would have to wait in queue to be executed one after another. It seems to me, when `conn.useDb('db2', { useCache: true }))` call checks out a connection, next `conn.useDb('db2', { useCache: true }))` will get the cached connection if only the checked out connection has released and returned to the pool, if not it won't wait for the connection to get released instead either it uses another available connections in the pool or if all the connections have been checked out resulting the pool being empty and maxPoolSize has not reached, it will create a new connection in the pool(if maxPoolSize's been reached, it would wait for a connection to return to the bool).